# Parsing JSON result from node oracledb

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, oracle

I am using oracledb with node and fetching data from it asynchronously. For the sake of ease, I have implemented it using separate files like below -

**config.js -**

```
module.exports = {
  user          : "user",
  password      : "password",
  connectString : "*connstring*"  ,
  deliveredQuery: " SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT order_num) AS Cnt from orders where department = 'HR'
};
```

**query2.js** :

```
module.exports = function(callback) {//pass callback function and return with this
  var oracledb = require('oracledb');
  var dbConfig = require('./config.js');

  this.queryDB = function(query,callback) {
    oracledb.getConnection({
      user: dbConfig.user,
      password: dbConfig.password,
      connectString: dbConfig.connectString,
      deliveredQuery: dbConfig.deliveredQuery    
    }, function(err, connection) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        return callback(err);
      }
      connection.execute(query, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          doRelease(connection);
          return;
        }
        //console.log(result.metaData);
        //console.log(JSON.parse(result.rows[0][0]));
        doRelease(connection);
        return callback(null, JSON.parse(result.rows[0][0]))
      });
    });

    function doRelease(connection) {
      connection.release(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          return callback(err);
        }
      });
    }
  };
};
```

**serv_ontime.js** :

```
var dbConfig = require('./config.js');
var res = require('./query2.js')();
var onTime_query = dbConfig.onTime_query;

module.exports = queryDB(onTime_query, function(err, callback){  });
```

**index.js** :

```
var res = require('./serv_ontime.js');
console.log("The result is= "+  res);
```

Now, When I am doing - node index.js from my cmd then I am getting the output as **[object Object]**. I suppose it is because the call is happening asynchronously. But if you see in the file **query2.js** , I am returning the value after parsing(using JSON.parse) but still the value I am getting in the **index.js** file is not the parsed one. **How can I parse the value in index.js?** I have already tried JSON.parse but it doesn`t work.

Comment: I think everything is ok, just change `console.log("The result is= "+  res);` to `console.log("The result is= ",  res);` and you well see result

Comment: @ponury-kostek You`re right regarding the concatenation part. But I suppose the problem is something else here. Moreover, I used module.export instead of *module.exports* which I have edited now.

I am getting the output as 'undefined' . I am not able to understand why is that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `serv_ontime.js` you are exporting result of `queryDB` witch indeed is `undefined`. Ty this:

**serv_ontime.js**

```
var dbConfig = require('./config.js');
var res = require('./query2.js')();
var onTime_query = dbConfig.onTime_query;

module.exports = function (callback) {
    queryDB(onTime_query, callback)
};
```

**index.js**

```
var serv_ontime = require('./serv_ontime.js');
serv_ontime(function(error, res) {
    console.log("The error is= ", error);
    console.log("The result is= ", res);
});
```

Comment: This works superb. I have one small doubt here, if you could help. I see again callback has to be used to get the value. What I am trying to do here is, doing multiple queryDB for different sql queries and trying to create a JSON object in the index.js file that I could send to client side using the app. get(). Could you help me understand if it is even possible to create such an Object ? Because we are essentially using callback for every value that I fetch.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting output as `[object Object]` because you are doing `+` with a String(`'The result is= '`), So js engine tries to convert the `Object` to a `String`. To view it as an `Object`, do log it separately or log with comma separated,

```
console.log('The result is= ', res); (or)
console.log(res); // or console.dir(res)
```

Or you can get String version of it, by doing `JSON.stringify(res)`

```
console.log('The result is= ', JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: You`re right regarding the concatenation part. But I suppose the problem is something else here. Moreover, I used module.export instead of *module.exports* which I have edited now.

I am getting the output as 'undefined' . I am not able to understand why is that.